# PDO: How can I etrieve an image address from MySQL and print it?

Tags: mysql, image, pdo

I'm stepping up from mysql to PDO and I'm getting close as all my fields print now except the images. These are held in a separate file with only the address in the database. I can retrieve these in mysql but I'm having trouble doing it in PDO.

Where I should see the image, the best I've been able to achieve is getting it to print "Arrayh" at the end of each line. I don't seem to be able to find how to do this anywhere so here I am again. This is the part of the file that prints.

```
$STM->bindParam(':Country', $Country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STM->execute();                    
$row= $STM->fetchAll();

$img_url = "http://www.xxxxx.net/images/";
if(count($row)){
foreach($row as $data){
    echo $data['Country'] ." ".$data['Year']." ".$data['Description']." ".$data.$img_url['Images']."<br />";

}
}else {
echo 'no row found';
 }
```

Comment: $data is array but you are echoing it in foreach while $img_url is string and you are sccessing it like array.

Comment: Thanks. I see that now. I just can't find how it should be done.

Comment: Don't mind @jjarm we are here for help to solve the problem not to write the code. If u really don't know then at least you should provide what data u have and what u want to represent.

Comment: Thanks developerCK and @meda. These two lines are as far as I got but I've tried dozens of different combinations so I feel that it is the basic logic that is wrong and that is what I can't find. $img_url = "http://www.xxxxx.net/images/";
if(count($row)){
foreach($row as $data){    echo $data['Key'] ." ".$data['Country'] ." ".$data['Year']." ".$data['Description']."<br />";
  echo "<img src='"$img_url.$data['Images']."'><br />"; The first line alone works perfectly but when I add any combination on the second I get a blank page. I tried meda's suggestion but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

Say if you called your image field `img_url`

```
foreach($row as $data){
    echo "<img src='"$data['img_url']."'><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually got it to work so I will put what I've used here otherwise this question will be useless for people in the future who have the same problem. The echo data line is replaced by two lines :

```
 echo $data['Key'] ."   ".$data['Country'] ."   ".$data['Year']."   ".$data['Description']."  ";
   echo "<img src='$img_url".$data['Images']."' <br /><br />" ; 
   "<br />";
```

Now I just need to get it into a table to neaten it up a bit. Thanks to all who helped.